# Galaxy Ace with 'Ace of Spades' not compatible with your device app

Tags: galaxy, google-play

I have developed an app, "Guia Dos Mares La Manga", and it was found in my Galaxy Ace with the original OS but after flashing to Ace of Spades V3, everything goes fine but this apps which does not appear in the PLAY from the phone. If I look for it from a PC, PLAY tells me that this "This item is not compatible with your device." when with the previous OS was fine.

I have reviewed the code and the Manifest but everything looks fine. I have read several post with a similar problem with no luck. It is neither the SDK version, nor the maturity level, not the permitions, not the uses-features, I am getting crazy becuase it is the only app which does not appear in my phone.

Is it possible to know what is the reason that the Google Play says "This item is not compatible with your device."?

Comment: Please write your comment as an answer, accept it and remove that SOLVED tag. Thx :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the problem. Just to help anyone who has a similar problem. With some flashed devices, if the app is with copyright proteccion active in the product ifno tab at Google Play, the device will not see the app int the Google Play. The reason of this it is not clear to me, maybe somebody can provide some additional info.